# How to bind Data for Extjs grid 4 using json data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am reseaching about extjs gid 4. I have done ok with Array data but when i use json it not ok. Could you help me . what are js files i need to add on website.  If you can, could you give me detail about it.

Thank
Nguyen

Comment: 1. Check the json data set using jsonlint.com. 2. Post a sample of the store your grid is using.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON data you must use [Ext.data.JsonStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore). This store is a default [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) wich is configured with [Ext.data.reader.Json](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json). Also you can create your own DataReader for custom data models.